# Vectorized sum-reduction with outer product - NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm relatively new to NumPy and often read that you should avoid to write loops. In many cases I understand how to deal with that, but at the moment I have the following code:

```
p = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
w = np.random.rand(5)
A = np.sum(w[i] * np.outer(p[i], p[i]) for i in range(len(p)))
```

Does anybody know if there is there a way to avoid the inner for loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik,i->jk',p,p,w)
```

**Approach #2 :** With [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) + [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(p[...,None]*p[:,None], w, axes=((0),(0)))
```

**Approach #3 :** With `np.einsum` + [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,i->ji',p,w).dot(p)
```

---

#### Runtime test

Set #1 :

```
In [653]: p = np.random.rand(50,30)

In [654]: w = np.random.rand(50)

In [655]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ik,i->jk',p,p,w)
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop

In [656]: %timeit np.tensordot(p[...,None]*p[:,None], w, axes=((0),(0)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 124 µs per loop

In [657]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,i->ji',p,w).dot(p)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.07 µs per loop
```

Set #2 :

```
In [658]: p = np.random.rand(500,300)

In [659]: w = np.random.rand(500)

In [660]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ik,i->jk',p,p,w)
10 loops, best of 3: 139 ms per loop

In [661]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,i->ji',p,w).dot(p)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
```

The third approach just blew everything else!

**Why `Approach #3` is 10x-130x faster than `Approach #1`?**

`np.einsum` is implemented in C. In the first approach, with those three strings there `i`,`j`,`k` in its string-notation, we would have three nested loops (in C of course). That's a lot of memory overhead there.

With the third approach, we are only getting into two strings `i`, `j`, hence two nested loops (in C again) and also leveraging BLAS based `matrix-multiplication` with that `np.dot`. These two factors are responsible for the amazing speedup with this one.

Comment: Wow, thanks! The speedup of np.einsum is great!


`%timeit np.sum(w[i] * np.outer(p[i], p[i]) for i in range(len(p)))
76.8 µs ± 313 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`


`%timeit np.einsum('ij,ik,i->jk',p,p,w)
5.49 µs ± 43.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`


`%timeit np.tensordot(p[...,None]*p[:,None], w, axes=((0),(0)))
23.9 µs ± 510 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

Comment: @joe-92 Added timings for bigger arrays.

Comment: @Divakar, do you have any explanation with the combination of einsum and dot is faster than pure einsum?

Comment: It seems like NumPy 1.14 will use BLAS for `einsum` when possible (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases). Maybe this will increase the speed of the first approach.

Comment: @joe-92 Good news there! We just need to see how well that " when possible" part comes along. But promising stuff indeed.

Comment: It is possible to pre-calculate the einsum-path with `np.einsum_path` and to use it with `np.einsum(..., optimize=path)`. When doing this, the timings become comparable between approaches #1 and #3 (2.3 ms vs 2.22 ms for the bigger matrices on my laptop).